# Work around SQL array

Tags: sql, arrays

I know this question might have been asked many times, but I failed to find them. My original table is like this

```
    Location Language Component Score
    A        Eng         1        25
    A        Eng         2        30
    B        Eng         1        12
    B        Eng         2        50
```

Expected Output:

```
    Location Language  Score1    Score2
    A        Eng         25       30
    B        Eng         12       50
```

Thanks!

Comment: If your engine is sql server You can use PIVOT tables, you can look into this : [Pivot tables in SQL Server. A simple sample.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  Location, 
  Language,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Component = 1 THEN Score ELSE 0 END) AS  Score1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Component = 2 THEN Score ELSE 0 END) AS  Score2,
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY Location, Language
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT S1.[Location], S1.[Language], S1.Score1, S2.Score2
    FROM
        (SELECT [Location], [Language], Score [Score1]
        FROM Scores WHERE Component = 1) S1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT [Location], [Language], Score [Score2]
        FROM Scores WHERE Component = 2) S2 ON S1.[Location] = S2.[Location] 
            AND S1.[Language] = S2.[Language]
```